# Reading integers from file in c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I currently have a plain text file which contains three tables as follows:

```
0  0  0  0
20 20 0  0
100 150 150 150 
100 0 0 0
0 255 255 255


0 0 0 255
20 100 100 100
0 0 0 0
100 100 250 250
255 255 0  0


0 100 255 0
20 100 100 100
0 0 0 0
100 20 20 100
0 255 255 255
```

Each table represents RGB values for an image. The first table is all red, second table all green, third table all blue. I have int arrays red[][], green[][] and blue[][] that I want to store these values into.

I currently have a loop:

```
string data;
int count = 0;
while (getline(infile, data))
{
    // iterate though data line and store into array
    count++;
}
```

I definitely know that if count < 5 I should store into red array, < 11 into green array, etc, but I'm unsure how to get each individual number out for storage. What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `data` string to initialize an `istringstream` and extract the `int`s, for example:

```
while (getline(infile, data))
{
  std::istringstream iss(data);
  int i, j, k;
  iss >> i >> j >> k;
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Will this work if the line is empty though? there are empty lines

Comment: @JonMartin You'll have to keep track of the empty lines yourself somehow, you might want to reconsider your file format.

Comment: instead of `count++;` do `if ( iss ) { /* line had 3 numbers */ } else { /* line didn't have 3 numbers */ }`

Comment: If you need to support a variable number of numbers per line then you'll need to change `iss >> i >> j >> k` into `while ( iss >> i ) { /* do something with i */ }`

Comment: @MattMcNabb indeed there is a lot that can be improved here.

Comment: @JonMartin `#include <sstream>` ?

Comment: How to do this elegantly only using `c` instead of `c++` ?

Comment: @tenos search SO, there are plenty of examples.